# How to modify the link to access user profile?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, osqa

I would like to modify the url to access user profile. OSQA use [permalink()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.permalink) to generate the profile url
 The default link is http://meta.osqa.net/users/2836/nhatthinh
And I want to change it to http://meta.osqa.net/users/nhatthinh
So, I modify the function **get_profile_url** follow as:

```
 @models.permalink
    def get_profile_url(self):
        return ('user_profile', [slugify(self.username)])
```

And I also modify the url in forum\urls.py follow as:

```
url(r'^%s/(.*)/$' % _('users/'), app.users.user_profile, name='user_profile'),
```

But the result falls short of my expectation.
OSQA generates a link is http://meta.osqa.net/users//nhatthinh
So, how can I fix this issue?
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try it like that:

```
url(r'^%s/(.*)/$' % _('users'), app.users.user_profile, name='user_profile'),
```

And if you use tranlsations, do not forget to adapt these as well.